# question with Sorting change in java to decimals

Tags: java

Hi I need help with sorting change into decimals like quarters,pennies, nickels,etc. It says a possible lossy conversion. Here is my code:

```
public class Assignment04 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your amount");
        long amount = stdin.nextLong();
        long remainder = Math.round(amount * 100 );


        long hundreds = (int) remainder / 10000;
        remainder = remainder % 10000;

        long fifties = (int) remainder / 5000;
        remainder = remainder % 5000;

        long twenties = (int)remainder / 2000;
        remainder = remainder % 2000;

        long tens = (int)remainder / 1000;
        remainder = remainder % 1000;

        long fives = (int)remainder / 500;
        remainder = remainder % 500;

        long ones = (int)remainder / 100;
        remainder = remainder % 100;

        long quarters = remainder / .25;
        remainder = remainder % .25;

        long dimes =  (int)remainder / .10;
        remainder = remainder % .10;

        long nickels =  (int)remainder / .5;
        remainder = remainder % .5;

        double pennies = (int) remainder;




        System.out.println(hundreds + "hundred/s");
        System.out.println(fifties + "fiftie/s");
        System.out.println(twenties + "twentie/s");
        System.out.println(tens + "ten/s");
        System.out.println(fives + "five/s");
        System.out.println(ones + "one/s");
        System.out.println(quarters + "quarter/s");
        System.out.println(dimes + "dime/s");
        System.out.println(nickels + "nickel/s");
        System.out.println(pennies + "cent/s");

    }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to remove the red underlines so it can be ran correctly. I'm mostly done I just got confused when it came to decimals.

Comment: What logic are you expecting with `long quarters = remainder / .25;` ? BTW this is equal to `long quarters = remainder * 4;` but I don't think it is what you want.

Comment: so when I put / .25 that means im basically multiplying * 4. in that case will remainder / 4 work?

Comment: Sorry not my currency, but assuming that `ones` equals `remainder / 100` then wouldn't `quarters` equal `remainder / 25` ?

Comment: yea that sounds about right. I'll try it out thanks

Comment: like float or double? I put both of those for quarters and it would not run

Comment: double quarters = remainder / 25;

Comment: I tried that and it said input mismatch exception and it also said build failure

Comment: I also have my variables as int not long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your remainder field appears to be expressed in cents.

- $100 = 10000
- $20 = 2000
- $1 = 100

Therefore, a quarter should be 25, a dime should be 10 and a nickel should be 5.

Also change this:

```
double pennies = (int) remainder;
```

to this:

```
long pennies = remainder;
```

Fix the scanner input of amount and remove the casting to (int) for all lines that end up getting stored in a long:

```
public class Assignment04 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your amount");
        long remainder = Math.round(stdin.nextDouble() * 100 );


        long hundreds = remainder / 10000;
        remainder = remainder % 10000;

        long fifties = remainder / 5000;
        remainder = remainder % 5000;

        long twenties = remainder / 2000;
        remainder = remainder % 2000;

        long tens = remainder / 1000;
        remainder = remainder % 1000;

        long fives = remainder / 500;
        remainder = remainder % 500;

        long ones = remainder / 100;
        remainder = remainder % 100;

        long quarters = remainder / 25;
        remainder = remainder % 25;

        long dimes = remainder / 10;
        remainder = remainder % 10;

        long nickels = remainder / 5;
        remainder = remainder % 5;

        long pennies = remainder;




        System.out.println(hundreds + "hundred/s");
        System.out.println(fifties + "fiftie/s");
        System.out.println(twenties + "twentie/s");
        System.out.println(tens + "ten/s");
        System.out.println(fives + "five/s");
        System.out.println(ones + "one/s");
        System.out.println(quarters + "quarter/s");
        System.out.println(dimes + "dime/s");
        System.out.println(nickels + "nickel/s");
        System.out.println(pennies + "cent/s");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use int . instead of long. i hope this help. thanks

```
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
            int amount;
            int remainder;
            System.out.print("Enter amount:");
            amount= (int) Math.round(stdin.nextDouble() * 100);
            int hundreds= remainder / 1000;
                if (hundreds > 0) {
                    remainder = remainder% 1000;
                    System.out.println(hundreds + "hundred/s");
                }

     int fifties = remainder / 1000;
                        if (fifties > 0) {
                            remainder = remainder% 1000;
                            System.out.println(fifties + "fiftie/s");
                    }
                // number of twenties for remainder.
                int twenties = change / 2000
                if (twenties > 0) { 
                    remainder= remainder % 2000; // this resets the value of remainder to
                    // the remainder after the twenties are
                    // calculated but only if there was at
                    // least enough to make one twenty
                    System.out.println(twenties + "twentie/s");
                }

                int tens = remainder / 1000;
                if (tens > 0) {
                    remainder = remainder% 1000;
                    System.out.println(tens + " ten/s");
                }

                int fives = remainder/ 500;
                if (fives > 0) {
                    remainder= remainder% 500;
                    System.out.println(fives + " five/s");
                }

                int ones = remainder/ 100;
                if (ones > 0) {
                    remainder = remainder % 100;
                    System.out.println(ones + " one/s");
                }

                int quarters = remainder/ 25;
                if (quarters > 0) {
                    remainder= remainder% 25;
                    System.out.println(quarters + " quarter/s");
                }

                int dimes = remainder/ 10;
                if (dimes > 0) {
                    remainder = remainder % 10;
                    System.out.println(dimes + " dime/s");
                }

                int nickels = remainder/ 5;
                if (nickels > 0) {
                    remainder= change % 5;
                    System.out.println(nickels + " nickel/s");
                }
                int pennies = remainder;
                System.out.println(pennies + " cent/s");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score -2):

I fixed it by converting amount and remainder into double.

Comment: If amount is supposed to be measured in cents (which it appears your code expects), then you don't need double, since it's not possible to have a fraction of a cent. So long (or int, depending on the maximum amount your code should support) is correct - no need for floating point representation.

Comment: So i should have amount and remainder as an int or long?

Comment: If `remainder` is in units of cents, and there's no way to have a fraction of a cent, then there's no need for it to be a float or double.